# Order dynamically created html table using JavaScript like snakes and ladders game

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have created a table using javascript and HTML. The table has 50 cells. The cells begin at 50 and end at 1. This is what it looks like now and my code:

[image: Now]

I am creating a snakes and ladders game. So 1 needs to begin on the left bottom corner and so on like this:

[image: Need]

Is there a way to do this easily or do I need to program each row myself the way I want it?

This is my code so far:

Html:

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script>
     var link = document.createElement('link');
     link.rel = 'stylesheet';
     link.type = 'text/css';
     link.href = 'style.css';
     document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0].appendChild(link);
 </script>
 </head>
 <html lang="en">

 <body>
 <div>
     <button id="selectbtn" type="button" >Create </button>
     <button id="btnMove" type="button" >move to ?</button>
 </div>
     <div id="myDynamicTable">
     </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Script:

```
document.getElementById("selectbtn").addEventListener("click", addTable);
 function addTable() {   
 document.getElementById("selectbtn").hidden=true;
 var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");            
 var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
 table.border='1';        
 //table.className = "table";
 var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
 table.appendChild(tableBody);
    
 var n = 50;
 var even = true;
 
 for (var i=0; i<5; i++){         
     var tr = document.createElement('TR');            
     tableBody.appendChild(tr);         
     for (var j=0; j<10; j++){
         var td = document.createElement('TD');                
         td.width='75';
         td.height = '75';
         td.id = n;
         if(even){
             td.className = "even"
             even = false
         }
         else{
            td.className = "odd"  
            even = true 
         }
         var img = document.createElement('img');
         img.id = "img"+n;
         td.appendChild(img);
         td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(n));
         tr.appendChild(td);
         n--;            
     }
 }
 myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
}
```

Thank you in advance